# Apollo Server Upload File failes in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker

**UPD** **After several hours I've got a bright idea of trying another node version in docker. Alpine gave that error while 10.15 works fine.**

I have the following function in my resolver to upload the file through apollo graphql

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype } = file
if (!(mimetype === 'image/png' || mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || mimetype === 'image/jpg')){
  const error = new Error('Forbidden file type ', mimetype)
  error.code = 415
  reject(error)
}

const savedFileName = uuidv4()+path.extname(filename)
const savedFile = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'images', subDir, savedFileName)
const imagePath = path.join('/images', subDir, savedFileName).replace(/\\/g, "/")

const readStream  = createReadStream()

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(savedFile, { flags : 'w' });
readStream.pipe(writeStream)

readStream.on('error', () => console.log('reading error'))
writeStream.on('finish', () => resolve({file: savedFile, imageUrl: imagePath}))
writeStream.on('error', (error) => {

  //const err = new Error('Error writing file')
  //error.code = 422
  reject(error)
})
```

It works fine in my development enviroment in Windows. I tried to create docker containers for my project and this snippet fails with in error:

```
internal/fs/streams.js:120
node_1      | function _openReadFs(stream) {
node_1      |                     ^
node_1      |
node_1      | RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
node_1      |     at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:120:21)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:116:3)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:70:15)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.open (/app/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:90:11)
node_1      |     at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:123:12)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:116:3)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:70:15)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.open (/app/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:90:11)
node_1      |     at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:123:12)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:116:3)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:70:15)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.open (/app/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:90:11)
node_1      |     at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:123:12)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:116:3)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:70:15)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.open (/app/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:90:11)
node_1      |     at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:123:12)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:116:3)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:70:15)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.open (/app/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:90:11)
node_1      |     at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:123:12)
node_1      |     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:116:3)
node_1      | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm new to docker and especcialy to linux. Maybe there is a difference how reading and piping processed in linux. But I don't understand where to look. Is it a Apollo problem or docker problem or my linux poor knowledge problem.
Will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: I am having the same issues now, works fine outside of docker but soon as I use my express container I get this issue, the file seems to get to the server ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to node deprecating some internal stream APIs, see [DEP0135: WriteStream.open() and ReadStream.open() are internal](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0135_writestream_open_and_readstream_open_are_internal).

> `WriteStream.open()` and `ReadStream.open()` are undocumented internal
>   APIs that do not make sense to use in userland. File streams should
>   always be opened through their corresponding factory methods
>   `fs.createWriteStream()` and `fs.createReadStream()`) or by passing a
>   file descriptor in options.

There is an issue filed to try and get this all sorted: [Upgrade graphql-upload to 9.0 to support Node.JS 13](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3579#issue-532553049).  The crux is that [fs-capacitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-capacitor) has been updated to address this, but everything that depends on it needs to update accordingly.

For now, you'll need to use node 12 or at least something prior to 13.

Comment: Is still an issue on Node 14. Downgrading to Node 12 solved this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by using the more current version of node by explicitly defining it in my 'Dockerfile', my local environment is running v11.14.0, you can check yours via

```
node -v
```

Once I modified my 'Dockerfile' to use

```
FROM node:11
```

in my opening line it worked first try after that.

Hope this helps you